# Well-known binary (WKB) to decimal latitude/longitude

Tags: algorithm, gis, java

There is a table in a geoDB with fields in Well-known binary (WKB) data format. I would like to get latitude and longitude from this binary data in normal decimal format independent from DB (with Java for example). Does any library or code example exist for such transformation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a solution yet, but I found a free Java library. Info [Here](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jcs/) and download page [Here](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/download.htm).

From what I can tell it supports WKB and WKT as well as a few others.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Select the data from the geometry field using the AsText(Geometry) function. This gives you the geometry object in a textural representations. If you have to draw on a web page use AsSVG(Geometry) and you get the data as SVG